# Python asyncio: Queue concurrent to normal code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

Edit: I am closing this question.
As it turns out, my goal of having parallel HTTP posts is pointless. After implementing it successfully with aiohttp, I run into deadlocks elsewhere in the pipeline.
I will reformulate this and post a single question in a few days.

**Problem**

I want to have a class that, during some other computation, holds generated data and can write it to a DB via HTTP (details below) when convenient. It's gotta be a class as it is also used to load/represent/manipulate data.

I have written a naive, nonconcurrent implementation that works:
The class is initialized and then used in a "main loop". Data is added to it in this main loop to a naive "Queue" (a list of HTTP requests). At certain intervals in the main loop, the class calls a function to write those requests and clear the "queue".

As you can expect, this is IO bound. Whenever I need to write the "queue", the main loop halts. Furthermore, since the main computation runs on a GPU, the loop is also not really CPU bound.

Essentially, I want to have a queue, and, say, ten workers running in the background and pushing items to the http connector, waiting for the push to finish and then taking on the next (or just waiting for the next write call, not a big deal). In the meantime, my main loop runs and adds to the queue.

**Program example**

My naive program looks something like this

```
class data_storage(...):
    def add(...):

    def write_queue(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            res = self.connector.run(self.queue)
            self.queue = []


def main_loop(storage):
    # do many things

    for batch in dataset: #simplified example
         # Do stuff
         for some_other_loop:
              (...)
              storage.add(results)

         # For example, call each iteration
         storage.write_queue()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    storage=data_storage()
    main_loop(storage)
...
```

In detail: the connector class is from the package 'neo4j-connector' to post to my Neo4j database. It essentially does JSON formatting and uses the "requests" api from python. 
This works, even without a real queue, since nothing is concurrent.

Now I have to make it work concurrently.
From my research, I have seen that ideally I would want a "producer-consumer" pattern, where both are initialized via asyncio. I have only seen this implemented via functions, not classes, so I don't know how to approach this. With functions, my main loop should be a producer coroutine and my write function becomes the consumer. Both are initiated as tasks on the queue and then gathered, where I'd initialize only one producer but many consumers.

My issue is that the main loop includes parts that are already parallel (e.g. PyTorch). Asyncio is not thread safe, so I don't think I can just wrap everything in async decorators and make a co-routine. This is also precisely why I want the DB logic in a separate class.

I also don't actually want or need the main loop to run "concurrently" on the same thread with the workers. But it's fine if that's the outcome as the workers don't do much on the CPU. But technically speaking, I want multi-threading? I have no idea.

My only other option would be to write into the queue until it is "full", halt the loop and then use multiple threads to dump it to the DB. Still, this would be much slower than doing it while the main loop is running. My gain would be minimal, just concurrency while working through the queue. I'd settle for it if need be.

However, from a stackoverflow post, I came up with this small change

```
class data_storage(...):
    def add(...):

    def background(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    @background
    def write_queue(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            res = self.connector.run(self.queue)
            self.queue = []
```

Shockingly this sort of "works" and is blazingly fast. Of course since it's not a real queue, things get overwritten. Furthermore, this overwhelms or deadlocks the HTTP API and in general produces a load of errors.

But since this - in principle - works, I wonder if I could do is the following:

```
class data_storage(...):
    def add(...):

    def background(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    @background
    def post(self, items):
        if len(items) > 0:
            self.nr_workers.increase()
            res = self.connector.run(items)
            self.nr_workers.decrease()

    def write_queue(self):         
         if self.nr_workers < 10:
               items=self.queue.get(200) # Extract and delete from queue, non-concurrent
               self.post(items) # Add "Worker"
```

for some hypothetical queue and nr_workers objects. Then at the end of the main loop, have a function that blocks progress until number of workers is zero and clears, non-concurrently, the rest of the queue.

This seems like a monumentally bad idea, but I don't know how else to implement this. If this is terrible, I'd like to know before I start doing more work on this. Do you think it would it work?

Otherwise, could you give me any pointers as how to approach this situation correctly?
Some key words, tools or things to research would of course be enough.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but this question does not appear answerable. There are just too many topics to cover, that an answer would be book-length, and it might still not suit you. The question is about class design, use of queues, multi-threading and `run_in_executor`, integration with PyTorch, and migrating off requests. I recommend to start using asyncio on a simpler task, and as you learn, ask questions about concrete _individual_ issues that you encounter.

Comment: Fair point. My fiddling revealed that parallel writes to Neo4j are not a good idea anyway. Hence, it seems the only way to solve this problem would be to run one thread for HTTP Posts, and one thread for filling a queue. Since this is not something asyncio does, my question is pointless.